# DBeaver dont show meta data of external table

Tags: dbeaver, external-tables, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have external tables (spectrum in S3).
I can query them without any problem but when im trying to expand my table columns im getting this error:
[image]

Does someone knows how can I fix it and show the external table meta data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What DBeaver version do you use? We fixed this [issue](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/13133) a few months ago. Maybe an update of the DBeaver version will help you.